# Kotlin Native convert ByteArray to ULong/Unsinged Long

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

How to convert a ByteArray to ULong in kotlin.

```
val byteArray = byteArrayOf(
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private fun UByteArray.toLong() = reversed().foldIndexed(0L) { index, acc, byte -> acc + (byte.toLong() shl index * 8) }
```

Unit Tests...

```
    @Test
fun uByteArrayToLongTest() {
    assertEquals(284L, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0x1c.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(285L, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0x1d.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(286L, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0x1e.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(287L, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0x1f.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(288L, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0x20.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(510, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0xfe.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(511, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0xff.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(512, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x02.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(513, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x02.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(65534, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0xff.toUByte(), 0xfe.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(65535, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0xff.toUByte(), 0xff.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(65536, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
    assertEquals(65537, listOf(0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte(), 0x00.toUByte(), 0x01.toUByte()).toUByteArray().toLong())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun UByteArray.getULongBe() =
    ((this[7].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 56) or
            ((this[6].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 48) or
            ((this[5].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 40) or
            ((this[4].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 32) or
            ((this[3].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 24) or
            ((this[2].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 16) or
            ((this[1].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 8) or
            (this[0].toULong() and 0xFFu)

fun UByteArray.getULongLe() =
    ((this[0].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 56) or
            ((this[1].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 48) or
            ((this[2].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 40) or
            ((this[3].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 32) or
            ((this[4].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 24) or
            ((this[5].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 16) or
            ((this[6].toULong() and 0xFFu) shl 8) or
            (this[7].toULong() and 0xFFu)

val uByteArray = ubyteArrayOf(
    UByte.MAX_VALUE, UByte.MAX_VALUE,
    UByte.MAX_VALUE, UByte.MAX_VALUE,
    UByte.MAX_VALUE, UByte.MAX_VALUE,
    UByte.MAX_VALUE, UByte.MAX_VALUE,
)

ULong.MAX_VALUE 
// 18446744073709551615

uByteArray.getULongBe()
// 18446744073709551615
uByteArray.getULongLe()
// 18446744073709551615

val byteArray = byteArrayOf(
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
)

byteArray.toUByteArray().getULongLe()
// 1
byteArray.toUByteArray().getULongBe()
// 72057594037927936
```